# How to remove comments from all nodes

Tags: comments

I want to remove the comment section from all my articles. Can this be done with an sql query or something so I don't have to do it manually by setting comments to disabled ?

Answer (score 1):

Delete the comment fields from the Article content type and uninstall the Comment module.

Comment: Is there another way so I can still use comments for certain pages if I ever want to ?

Comment: You asked how to remove them entirely.